# Problems with hms conversions and conditionals

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a 2 column df, both characters, but one column is actually a time (h:m) column. I would like to create a new column called "DAY.NIGHT" based on whether the existing time column has a value between 8am-6pm or between 6pm-8am.

I have attempted to use the hms package to convert the existing time column into a hms type and I feel like maybe it has something to do with the other packages I have attached because sometimes my code as it is works, but then randomly it will stop working and I can't get it to work again.

Does anyone have an alternate way perhaps to achieve what I am trying to without using the hms package?

**EDIT 1:** True to form I just ran it again (without changing anything) and it has randomly worked. Same thing happened yesterday. So again if anyone has an alternate way to achieve this without the hms package it would be great.

**EDIT 2** Below is the error I tend to get. The odd thing is it sometimes will work but most of the time I get this error:

```
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `DAY.NIGHT = ifelse(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.
Caused by error:
! All arguments must be numeric or NA
---
Backtrace:
  1. time_agg %>% rowwise() %>% ...
  8. hms::hms(TIME)
  9. hms:::check_args(args)
 10. base::stop("All arguments must be numeric or NA", call. = FALSE)
```

Here is an extract of my script where the issue is:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(scales) 
library(viridis) 
library(hrbrthemes) 
library(e1071) 
library(rstatix)
library(GGally)
library(hms)

df_time <- data.frame(
  REGION = rep(c("NSW", "VIC", "QLD", "SA", "TAS"), each=50),
  TIME = rep(c("00:00", "08:00", "12:00", "21:00", "22:00"), each=10))
)

df_time$TIME <- as_hms(df_time$TIME)

day.night <- df_time %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate('DAY.NIGHT'= ifelse(
    hms(TIME) > hms("8:00:00") & 
      hms(TIME) < hms("18:00:00"), "DAY", "NIGHT"))
```

Comment: The `hms` package is a good way to do this. Your `rowwise` is probably unnecessary and certainly slowing your code down. If you're having trouble where you run things and sometimes they work and sometimes they don't, that usually indicates a bit of sloppiness: maybe you are (a) loading packages in inconsistent orders and masking functions, (b) running some code in the console only, not saving it in your script, (c) jumping around in your script and missing lines or running them out of order, (d) are using `attach()`. Avoid all those. Semi-frequently restart R and run your script from the top.

Comment: The `hms` and `lubridate` packages both contain an `hms()` function so it would be worth being explicit when calling the one you want by doing `hms::hms()` if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried them all (removing rowwise but also leaving in). I have loaded on packages at the start with the exception of hms where I load it only where I need it in the script. I have added hms:: to the hms function call and also run script from top to bottom. I have added a new comment in the my original post with the error.

Comment: Sorry I am newer to r so how can I share some of the actual data I am using rather than creating a sample? And to answer your question, yes even the small sample data I have created as the same hit and miss result. I restarted my session and then loaded only the 2 packages I need for the sample data (hms and tidyverse) but I am still getting the error.

Comment: That's perfect, I was able to reproduce the issue. Think I've got a fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your error with your first line, `df_time$TIME <- as_hms(df_time$TIME)`. I think it's because `as_hms` expects to have hours, minutes, and seconds, but your input doesn't have seconds. Let's paste on the seconds:

```
## add :00 seconds for no error
df_time$TIME <- as_hms(paste0(df_time$TIME, ":00"))
```

Once the `TIME` column is already `hms` class, you **don't** want to use `hms()` on it again. And we want to be using `as_hms()` not `hms`. (`hms()` looks like it would be appropriate if you were supplying the H, M, and S as separate arguments.)

```
day.night <- df_time %>%
  mutate('DAY.NIGHT'= ifelse(
    TIME > as_hms("8:00:00") & 
      TIME < as_hms("18:00:00"), "DAY", "NIGHT"))
## no warnings, no errors, should run consistently if your inputs are consistent
day.night
#     REGION     TIME DAY.NIGHT
# 1      NSW 00:00:00     NIGHT
# 2      NSW 00:00:00     NIGHT
# 3      NSW 00:00:00     NIGHT
# 4      NSW 00:00:00     NIGHT
# 5      NSW 00:00:00     NIGHT
# 6      NSW 00:00:00     NIGHT
# ...
```

Comment: Life saver!!! Thank you so much. To help my learning further, just curious how you figured it out? Was it based on knowledge and experience of using hms or did you need to read something or trial and error etc? Again thank you so much! Worked immediately and I am sure I wouldnt have figured it out on my own!

Comment: I don't recall using `hms` before, but just taking things one step at a time. I got an error with that first line. I tried `as_hms("00:00")` and got the error with one value. Looked at the `?as_hms` documentation, the description didn't help, but down at the bottom the example is `as_hms("12:34:56")`. Ran that, no error. Ran `as_hms("00:00:00")`, no error. I've had similar problems with converting dates before, say, if there's a month and a year but no date, and I figured it out.

Comment: Also opened [an issue on the hms github](https://github.com/tidyverse/hms/issues/111), because this should have either worked or been more clear.